# Date could not be parsed

Tags: java, string, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I have a custom date string which is basically a concatenation of the last digit of the year, the number that corresponds to the month, the date, the hour, min, and seconds.
Sample data `String`: `171231120000`

I wanted it to format to something like: `2017-12-31T12:00:00` but it seems unparseable.

Can you help check what's wrong with my code below?

```
String dateInString = "171231120000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss");     
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: how does `171231120000` look like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` ?

Comment: also *m Minute in hour*

Comment: Your Format has to match the input string. You can not use is it this way.

    String dateInString = "2017-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");     
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);

It will work because the string has the same format.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse( "171231120000" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuMMddHHmmss" ) ).toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you missed `'T'` and wrote only `T` instead.

Check this [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on SimpleDateFormat.
You could try to substitute your code line to this one:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

**UPDATE**

Or this one:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMddd'T'HHmmss");
```

Depending on your string. I'm sure that you didn't write the right `T`. Try this!

Let me know if this helps you!

**UPDATE 2**

Util method to parse your string into `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");`

```
public String gerRightFormat(String input) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (i <= 4) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        } else if (i >= 5 && i <= 6) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        } else if (i >= 7 && i <= 9) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        } else if (i >= 10 && i <= 12) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        } else if (i >= 13 && i <= 15) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            output += "-";
        } else if (i == 5) {
            output += "T";
        } else if (i == 8) {
            output += ":";
        } else if (i == 11) {
            output += ":";
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Your `output` will be your date string in `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");`. Should work!

Comment: still unparseable.... I made my date string to "20171231120000" and used both your suggested formatter... :(

Comment: Try this `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

Comment: it converted the string to date but it is not in the expected output... here's how it is displayed: Sun Dec 31 12:00:00 CST 2017

Comment: To parse a date is important that all characters given to `SimpleDateFormat`'s constructor match with your plain string. Be sure that every character has a corresponding value. Example, if you write `yyyyMM` your string cannot be `2017223`. In documentation you'll find your answer, by the way. I'm happy to help you.

Comment: thank you... I also already read about that... but this legacy system that we use this is the format it sends to our system.

Comment: In this case you have to change your plain string. Maybe you could create a util method that change your string value to something parseable in this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Try to change your plain string to `1712-31T12:00:00`

Comment: I'm thinking of other way but it is not elegant... I could extract the year, month, date, etc. values from the string and construct the date?

Comment: You could use Java's `Calendar` to do that. It's great to manage `Date` objects. There you have documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: ok so I think I will go that route. gracias Manuel!

Comment: use `long dateInString = 171231120000L;` instead `String dateInString = "171231120000";`

Comment: ok will try now

Comment: You could create a method with a counter that formats your string into `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. Try something like a `for` loop that checks string's `charAt(index)`. If index is <= 4 then write the year into the string. Once index is at `4` index you add `-`, when index is over 6 you have to add another `-`... Do this for all the string should make the trick!

Comment: @SudhaVelan that will convert date in milliseconds but we don't need that. We need a right format to be parsed :) try my method yonan!

Comment: I just tried 171231120000L. it works when my formatter is yyyyMMddHHmmss. but still the output is not in the expected format: Sun Dec 31 12:00:00 CST 2017.
I guess I need to extract the year, month, date, etc. from this date and reconstruct the date

Comment: I update my answer with the util method @yonan2236

Comment: ok will try now

Comment: do I need to just supply my dateSTring to the method?

Comment: it says unparseable... here's how my codes look like:

`String dateInString = "171231120000";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); 
  Date date = sdf.parse(gerRightFormat(dateInString));
  
  System.out.println(date);`

Comment: I think got it but there must be some error in the logic, here's the output of your util method: 20171-23T112:000:0

I will try to update your code/

Comment: check indexes of util method and try to reduce them by 1. I didn't test method. You can try to fix index, then should work fine :) sorry for this, I wrote it rapidly

Comment: I think to have found error. In the second if block reduce all indexes from 1. `if (i == 3) { //do something } else if (i == 5) { ...` do this for all if-else from `if (i == 4)` :)

Comment: I did what you say, it appears the output is still broken: 2017-12T311:200:00.

Comment: I think I can take it from here. I will figure this out. thank so far your help :)

Comment: No problem, it's a pleasure! If this helps you to solved the problem, please, set the answer as solved. Thanks :)

Comment: @yonan2236 Why is this Answer accepted? It discusses a formatting pattern unrelated to the input string. See [correct Answer by Titus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074181/642706).

Answer (score 0):

That is because the format of your date string is not `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` you should use a format that looks something like this `yyMMddhhmmss`

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the down vote ?

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct Answer. The accepted Answer does not match the Question.